How to self reference a calculated column in SQL (BigQuery)
I have a table like shown below:



row_number
usd
cad




1
10
13


2
15
18


3
-5
null


4
2
8


5
-11
null



I'm trying to write a SQL query in BigQuery to create a new_cad column that has the following logic:

If cad is not null, new_cad = cad
Else new_cad = (sum of all previous new_cad values) / (sum of all previous usd values) * cad, with the data ordered by row_number.

This is what I want the output of the query to look like:



row_number
usd
cad
new_cad




1
10
13
13


2
15
18
18


3
-5
null
-6.2


4
2
8
8


5
-11
null
-16.4



For example:

In row 3, new_cad = (13+18) / (10+15) * -5 = -6.2

In row 5, new_cad = (13+18-6.2+8) / (10+15-5+2) * -11 = -16.4


We can assume that row_number 1 will always have a value for cad.
I can use a window sum function to get the cumulative sum of usd, but can't figure out how to do the same for new_cad. Or maybe this requires a recursive query?

You need to use recursive query for this. Or you can use sum(cad) over (order by...

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateNullNewCardValues()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE current_id INT;
    DECLARE current_card DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE numerator DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE denominator DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id, card FROM cards WHERE new_card IS NULL;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    
    OPEN cur;
    
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur INTO current_id, current_card;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        SELECT SUM(new_card) INTO numerator FROM cards WHERE id < current_id AND new_card IS NOT NULL;
        SELECT SUM(card) INTO denominator FROM cards WHERE id < current_id AND new_card IS NOT NULL;
        UPDATE cards SET new_card = (numerator / denominator) * current_card WHERE id = current_id;
    END LOOP;
    
    CLOSE cur;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL UpdateNullNewCardValues();

